# Use a Content control in wpf application based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have made a content control in wpf that has 3 textboxes which works fine and can be used anywhere in application. But on one specific page I want to make the textboxes as editable and on other pages they should be non-editable.
How shall I move forward in this case ?
Eg: **Window 1** : `<ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Template="{StaticResource ContentControl1}">` (all textboxes inside content control must be non-editable) 
**Window 2**: `<ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Template="{StaticResource ContentControl1}">` 
(some textboxes inside the content control must be editable).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create another template that completely replaces `ContentControl1` or create a custom control with dependency properties to control whether the textboxes are editable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
<ContentControl.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
<Setter Property="TextBox.IsReadOnly"
Value="true" />
</Style>
</ContentControl.Style>
```

nested within the content control for the window where you want the text boxes to be not editable